# Nginx config for multiple Yii2 advanced project locations (Deploy Development)

Tags: php, nginx, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, api-design

I'm trying to setup ningx server file for one project with multiple versions on separated folders. I read a lot of different concepts and solutions but didn't get anywhere, I don't know anymore what is correct, so..

The purpose, is to build a good architecture while developing an API with different features but don't want to merge to our DEV branch yet, like:

- api.example.com/v1/user/auth (**dev**)
- api.example.com/**features/my-new-branch**/v1/user/auth (**my-new-branch**)

**1. Structure**

```
/var/www/html/project-api/
    /dev/ 
      api/ <- Advanced Yii2 Environment as frontend/backend
        modules/
          v1/
            controllers/
            models/
        web/
          index.php
      common/
      vendor/
      ...

    /my-new-branch/
      api/
        modules/
          v1/
            controllers/
            models/
        web/
          index.php
      common/
      vendor/
      ...
    /*/ <- Deploying more equal branches for in progress features
```

**2. Nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html/project-api/src/api/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name api.example.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project-api/dev-error.log notice;
    access_log off;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    ## Features (not working)
    location ~* ^/features/my-new-branch/(.+)$ {
      root /var/www/html/project-api/my-new-branch/api/web;
      try_files /api/web/$1 /api/web/$1/ /features/my-new-branch/index.php?$args;
      index /features/my-new-branch/$1/index.php;

      location ~ /\.(ht|git) {
        deny all;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/api/web/$1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;

        include fastcgi_params;
      }
    }
    ###########

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on socket
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {

      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_index index.php;

      include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
      access_log        off;
      log_not_found     off;
      expires           30d;
    }

    # deny access to . files, for security
    #
    location ~ /\. {
      log_not_found off;
      deny all;
     }
}
```

I have the current server configuration serving my development branch as normal php website, but I not finding a good solution for multiple php project nginx, with this structure on different roots and public folders (web).

Any solution? **Alias**, **root**, **rewrite**, **sublocations** .. ?

(Later) will be nice having our "**my-new-branch**" as variable to make this dynamic, as I deploying the new features on project folder.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias, root, sublocations or separated locations. I think rewrite isn't necessary.

I would rather do this with **Yii2 basic and modules**. One enter point and Yii2-app-basic urlMenager do all work.
I do not know, if this will help you but look at this [Yii2 NGINX advanced config](https://pceuropa.net/blog/nginx-config-yii2-advanced-project/)

sub my-new-branch in Yii2-app-advanced need change config file

```
    return [
    'homeUrl' => '/features/my-new-branch/',

    'components' => [

        'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/features/my-new-branch',
        ],
    ]
]
```